# few Services is not running after install a wix msi?

Tags: asp.net, wix, vdproj

I converted my vdproj into wix proj by using an converter.But when i built the wix project and install the setup.msi. the setup is install successfully but some of the services is not running.

Comment: I think if you need better solutions to your problem, you'll have to post a minimal code sample with this issue.

Comment: adding `wix` and `vdproj` tags

Comment: Did this "converter"  bring your installer class custom actions or author the ServiceInstall and ServiceControl elements?

Comment: +1 to Chris's comment. If you came directly from a Visual Studio setup project to WiX without changing the way you install and start services then you may well have some issues. WiX has support for the standard MSI actions that install/stop/start/delete services. If you carried forward your installer classes then you might well have difficulties.

Comment: this converter bring the installer class  and its method